# conflito de formulário de contatos ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Pessoal estou com um problema eu tenho dois fomularios de contato em ajax e esse esta dando conflito eu sei que o erro esta nesta linha

```
$('form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function (event) {
```

mas não sei exatamente como fazer com que o conflito deixe de acontecer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var $form1 = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form')
            if ($form1.length > 0) {
                $('form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function (event) {
                    if (event) event.preventDefault()
                    register($form1)
                })
            }
        })
        function register($form1) {
            $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('Sending...');
            $.ajax({
                type: $form1.attr('method'),
                url: $form1.attr('action'),
                data: $form1.serialize(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (err) { alert('Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later.') },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('subscribe')
                    if (data.result === 'success') {
                        // Yeahhhh Success
                        console.log(data.msg)
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').css('borderColor', '#ffffff')
                        $('#subscribe-result').css('color', 'rgb(53, 114, 210)')
                        $('#subscribe-result').html('<p>Thank you for subscribing. We have sent you a confirmation email.</p>')
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').val('')
                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user.
                        console.log(data.msg)
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').css('borderColor', '#ff8282')
                        $('#subscribe-result').css('color', '#ff8282')
                        $('#subscribe-result').html('<p>' + data.msg.substring(4) + '</p>')
                    }
                }
            })
        };
```

segue o codigo completo

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var $form1 = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form')
            if ($form1.length > 0) {
                $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function (event) {
                    if (event) event.preventDefault()
                    register($form1)
                })
            }
        })
        function register($form1) {
            $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('Sending...');
            $.ajax({
                type: $form1.attr('method'),
                url: $form1.attr('action'),
                data: $form1.serialize(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (err) { alert('Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later.') },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').val('subscribe')
                    if (data.result === 'success') {
                        // Yeahhhh Success
                        console.log(data.msg)
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').css('borderColor', '#ffffff')
                        $('#subscribe-result').css('color', 'rgb(53, 114, 210)')
                        $('#subscribe-result').html('<p>Thank you for subscribing. We have sent you a confirmation email.</p>')
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').val('')
                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user.
                        console.log(data.msg)
                        $('#mce-EMAIL').css('borderColor', '#ff8282')
                        $('#subscribe-result').css('color', '#ff8282')
                        $('#subscribe-result').html('<p>' + data.msg.substring(4) + '</p>')
                    }
                }
            })
        };
```

era so atribuir a id da form e não so form na linha do submit